# Number of upload limit inside a folder

Tags: folder, file, limitations

May I know the upload files limit inside a folder?

I mean each folder can contain how many files ?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such fix number for files to upload inside a folder.

**For SharePoint Online**:

According to the Microsoft's official documentation: [Service limits for all plans](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#service-limits-for-all-plans).

> - **Items in lists and libraries** - A list can have up to 30 million items and **a library can have up to 30 million files and folders.** After 100,000 items are added to a list, library, or folder, permission inheritance for the list, library, or folder can't be changed. To learn more about other restrictions for viewing large lists, see [Manage large lists and libraries in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).
> - **File size and file path length** - 15 GB. The maximum size for files attached to list items is 250 MB.

Also, According to the article, [Ultimate guide to SharePoint size and usage limitations](http://icansharepoint.com/menuntut-ilmu-main-judi-bandarq-online/):

> 1. Document libraries should not contain more than 30,000,000 documents (supported). That’s an insanely large amount. You can go larger than this amount, but Microsoft doesn’t recommend it.
> 2. By default the file size limit is set at:
>
>    - **SharePoint 2013**: 250 MB (supported), though your IT department can increase that to a hard maximum of 2 GB (boundary). But that 2-GB value is an absolute maximum. Unlike the 30,000,000 suggested limit above, the 2 GB file size can be very limiting at times, especially if we’re talking multimedia and video.
>    - **SharePoint 2016**: 2 GB (supported), though your IT department can increase that to a hard maximum of 10 GB (boundary). But that 10-GB value is an absolute maximum.
>    - **SharePoint Online**: 15 GB (boundary), only if you drag-and-drop the file. Other upload methods (e.g., the "upload" button) are limited to 2 GB.

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

30 Million is upper limit, whatever folder structure you have and number of folder you have....all together should not exceed 30 Million.

[Manage Large Libraries](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?CorrelationId=7a736c02-6c96-4e29-a4b4-693b33187e97&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Online)